# Defining decorator for a view function in flask

Tags: python, debugging, flask, python-decorators

I've tried to implement a minimal login sysem in flask, so I defined a decorator that checks if an element from the session has a particular value, if it does, the user can't access the page wrapped by that decorator.

This is the wrapped view function:

```
@mustBelongToARoom
@app.route('/draw')
def draw():
    return render_template('draw.html')
```

And this is the decorator

```
def mustBelongToARoom(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap_f(*args, **kwargs):
        print 'test\n'
        if session['room_name'] is None:
            return render_template(url_for('/'))
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap_f
```

So, basically, if the `room_name` is `None` the user can't access the `draw` page. 
The problem is that it seems to ignore the code added by the decorator. For example, take this version of the `mustBelongToARoom` decorator:

```
   def mustBelongToARoom(f):
        @wraps
        def wrap_f(*args, **kwargs):
            print 'test\n'
            if session['room_name'] is None:
                print '[DEBUG] you are not allowed to acces this page!\n'
                return render_template(url_for('/'))
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrap_f
```

I'd expect to see `[DEBUG] you are not allowed to acces this page!\n` in the console when an user tries to acces the `draw` page, but it doesn't display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reversing the order you apply the decorator.  The route decorator only added the `draw()` function and not the one returned by `mustBelongToARoom`, which includes your authentication scheme.

A good reference for how decorators work: [How to make a chain of function decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python#answer-1594484)